# Hover doesn't work

Tags: css

Hover effect doesn't work. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6WmnF/
I don't know why. When I remove hover and change the width attribute(as an example) it works. But hover or cursor attribute doesn't work, even when used seperately. I use latest google chrome version.

CSS:

```
#düzenleyici{
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 550px;
        height: 300px;
        box-shadow: -1px 1px 4px #000;
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        z-index:-1;
    }
    #araclar{
        width:auto;
        height:50px;
        background:#AAD3D4;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:5px 15px 5px 15px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    }
    #araclar>div{
        padding:0 5px 0 5px;
        display:inline-block;
        border:1px solid #606060;
        margin:0 3px 5px 3px;
        background:#F6F6F6;
        font-family:calibri;
    }
    #iclik{
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 100px;
        height: 267px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #000;
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        padding:33px 0 0 0;
        margin:0 0 0 -5px;
        z-index:1;
    }
    #araclar>div:hover{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tasarim.css" type="text/css"/>
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="düzenleyici">
        <div id="araclar">
            <div>
                Renk
            </div>
            <div>
                Yazı Tipi
            </div>
            <div>
                Yazı Boyutu
            </div>
            <div>
                Kalın
            </div>
            <div>
                İtalik
            </div>
            <div>
                Altı Çizili
            </div>
            <div>
                Resim Ekle
            </div>
            <div>
                Sola Daya
            </div>
            <div>
                Ortala
            </div>
            <div>
                Sağa Daya
            </div>
            <div>
                HTML Düzenleyicisi
            </div>
            <div>
                HTML Kodu Ek
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="iclik">
        asd
    </div>
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `z-index:-1;` is the issue. Do you have a reason for it?

Comment: It's because you have `z-index: -1;` on the container (`#düzenleyici`)

Comment: I didn't know that minus z-index causes this. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you set a `z-index` property for `#düzenleyici`. If not needed remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `z-index: -1` into the following section:

```
#düzenleyici {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Or change it to a positive value, if you need it.